# How can receive image into xamarin android?

Tags: c#, json, xamarin.android, webserver

How can I receive image in Xamarin android?

I have a program desktop storing image in SQL Server as binary data,
I want to receive this image in my app (Xamarin Android) using web server (Json)?

Help me please

Comment: Could it work ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes,for this you have to connect through webapi /web services. You could develop webapi with sql db operations and call web api from your Xamarin application.

You could look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/web-services/rest

and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-xamarin-android-get-started.

After that,you could retrieve the binary data from your sql server.

then display it in your `ImageView`

```
byte[] temp = xxxx; //retrieve from sql server
ImageView imageView = FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.xxxxx);
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.DecodeByteArray(temp, 0, temp.Length);
imageView.SetImageBitmap(bitmap);
```